# Clone GitHub Repo error: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: git, github, pem

I'm a new git user trying to follow a Lynda.com tutorial. I issued the exact command of the tutorial. I am using Windows 10, git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2. I have copied the following url(from the desired Github Repo) from GitHub and issued the following command and received the following error.

```
owner@LAPTOP-0FP78GPS /c/users/owner/Documents (master)
$ git clone https://github.com/kevinskoglund/explore_california.git lynda_version
Cloning into 'lynda_version'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/kevinskoglund/explore_california.git/': error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\cert.pem
  CApath: C:/RailsInstaller/Git/path/to/cacerts
```

Comment: "git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2" - this is _very_ old git, please consider installing a newer one from https://git-scm.com/download/win

Answer (score 5):

You have to locate the cert file path:

```
D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt
```

Configure the Git path:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo "D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt"
```

Or turn off SSL checks completely:

```
git config --system http.sslverify false
```

Comment: Plus one for turning off ssl checks.